# Get date and currency formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, localization, geolocation

Is there a way where I can get the user's configuration for date and currency formats, using JavaScript?

Comment: If you mean you want to get a string like "dd MMM yyyy" that describes the date format then no. If you are looking to be able to display a date using the local format then yes.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. You could *try* to use `new Date().toLocaleDateString()` and then reverse engineer the date format from that, but even this result will be browser-specific.

Comment: What would you do with the information, and what do you mean by the user’s configuration? Do you intend to read and write dates and currencies in the browser’s native formats, or in the user’s preferred format? (Two completely different things.)

Comment: I tough it won't be possible, all of you confirm that... Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can know the user's location by with [HTML5 geolocation](http://html5demos.com/geo) (or server side). And according to location, to know the currency. But you need a map of country -> currency.

HTML Basic Sample:

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else{
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}
function showPosition(position) {
  alert("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + " Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude) 
}
```

Comment: Knowing the location can tell you the currency for that location, but not the user's actual currency format settings. One thing that varies from country to country is whether commas and full-stops are used for thousands separators or decimal points, but if I was on holiday in Germany I wouldn't switch my computer's format to use `1.234,56`, I'd still want to see `1,234.56`.

Comment: You are right. So, just have as know the location and currency of that country. But if it's the native currency of the user, is impossible. We're talking about technology, not magic =P

Answer (score 0):

This sets a 'ddmm' property of Date to  true if the local computer parses (and outputs) date strings formatted as dd-mm-yyyy,
and false if the native format is mm-dd-yyyy.

```
Date.ddmm= (function(){
    return Date.parse('2/6/2009')== 1243915200000;
})();
```